# Reading file data using HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, encoding

I am attempting to read a file from a web service. The file is encrypted and the decryption function expects the input (cipher text) as a base 64 encoded string. The following code executes but I am unable to decrypt the resulting string.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_targetUrl));

request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.Headers.Add("Ent-APRF:FileIdentifier");

var cfsResponse = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

using (var rawResponseStream = cfsResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
if (rawResponseStream != null)
    using (var content = new StreamReader(rawResponseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            content.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);
            var myBytes = ms.ToArray();

            var encrypteddata = Convert.ToBase64String(myBytes);

            // call decrypt function suppling encrypted string
        }        
    }
}
```

A support person at the company providing the web service has sent me the same file by email and I can successfully read the file and decrypt, using the following code.

```
using (StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\Encrypted_TEST", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        myFile.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);
        var myBytes = ms.ToArray();

        var encrypteddata = Convert.ToBase64String(myBytes);

        // call decrypt function suppling encrypted string   
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if encoding may be issue because when I open the file sent by email in Notepad++ the encoding defaults to ANSI. However if I write the response bytes from the web call to file and open with Notepad++ the encoding defaults to UTF-8 with BOM.

I also include the request and response captured via Fiddler for completeness..

Request

```
GET https://url HTTP/1.1
Ent-APRF: FileIdentifier
Host: hostName
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 May 2015 23:51:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5767
Set-Cookie: ssnid=1b7eea90ff4b11e48bb9dd1cd2992cd2; path=/; HttpOnly
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive

0�w   *�H��
��h0�d1��0���0/0'1
0   UUS10U
...additional content body not included...
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: where is the code you successfully decrypt is shown ?..also where is the output from unsuccessful decrypt shown ?

Comment: The second code block shows reading the emailed file and results in successful decryption. The decrypt function is in a separate C dll, so where I have included the comment "// call decrypt function suppling encrypted string" is where that function is called. When the call to that function is unsuccessful an empty string is returned.

Comment: actually im asking where the output is actually displayed ?

Comment: @utility - thanks for taking the time to comment. I have now resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company providing the service made an adjustment to the file generation and encoding. I can now obtain and decrypt using the original code.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_targetUrl));

request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.Headers.Add("Ent-APRF:FileIdentifier");

var cfsResponse = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

using (var rawResponseStream = cfsResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
     if (rawResponseStream != null)
     using (var content = new StreamReader(rawResponseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
     {
         using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
             content.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);
             var myBytes = ms.ToArray();

             var encrypteddata = Convert.ToBase64String(myBytes);

             // call decrypt function suppling encrypted string
        }        
    }
}
```